# CiviMail space characters added

Tags: civimail

In CiviMail, in the subject or at the end of the text of the mail, spaces are added after certain number of characters.

How to solve that?

Screenshots of the problem below. An additional space between word European and agricultural.

[image: email in civimail ui]

[image: email in mail client]

Comment: can you provide a bit more of a clear example? eg screenshot, or similar on Demo site

Comment: and good to see civi in use by the organic umbrella organisation ;-)

Comment: so applying the patch mentioned by Thomas or waiting for the next release should solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did enounter the same issue earlier. I created an issue for it and proposed a patch: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20228

Comment: Interesting, does it work as well with utf8 subject lines? (I'm assuming writing them in german would have triggered the problem)

Comment: I have applying the patch. The problem is solved. Thanks  lot for help.